# Convert binary 32bit IEEE-754 floating points to Double in .net

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, floating-point

I'm trying to parse a binary [STereoLithography file(.stl)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)) in .net(C#) which has 32-bit floating-point numbers(IEEE-754) in it.

I need to parse those numbers and then later store those numbers in a string representation in a PovRay script, which is a plain text file.

I tried this in nodejs using the [readFloatLE](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readfloatle_offset_noassert) function which gives me back a Number(double-precision value).

In .net I only found the Bitconverter.ToSingle function which reads the binary 32bits and gives me a float which has less decimal precision(7) than the nodejs parsing.

The nodejs parsing gives a povray-script with nubmers like: -14.203535079956055
While the .net only gives me: -14.2035351

So, how do I parse the binary 32 bits to a Double in .net to get the higher precision?

[Edit]

Using the anwser from taffer: casting to converted float to a double and then using the 'round-trip' formatter for string representation.

Comparing to the nodejs output there are still minor rounding differences but those are in the 13th-16th decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not lose any precision. Unlike JavaScript, the default .NET `ToString` uses general number formatting, which may truncate the last digits.

But if you use the [round-trip format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#RFormatString) you get the exact result:

```
var d = double.Parse("-14.203535079956055");
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("R")); // displays -14.203535079956055
```

**Edit**

In JavaScript there is no 32-bit floating number type. Every `number` is a double. So even if you use the `readFloatLE` function, it will be parsed as a double from 32 bits. See the C# code below, which demonstrates what actually happens:

```
var d = (double)float.Parse("-14.2035351");
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("R")); // displays -14.203535079956055
```

Or even more precisely if you read the numbers from a byte buffer:

```
var d = (double)BitConverter.ToSingle(new byte[] { 174,65,99,193 }, 0);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("R")); // displays -14.203535079956055
```

Comment: Yes, that's because you're starting with a double. I only got 32 bits == 4 bytes == a float in .net: BitConverter.ToSingle(takes 4 bytes)

Comment: I agree with your answer, probably he reads the number as 64 bit in javascript.